# Access a LAN router while connected to a different WiFi

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, lan

I access the internet through my Wi-Fi network, managed by a Sagemcom router provided by my ISP.

I have an old(ish) Netgear router that is still working perfectly, and I want to log onto it via an Ethernet cable while connected to the Wi-Fi so that I can update its firmware and set it up to work when connected via WAN to the ONT (Optical Network Terminal).

I made multiple attempts but cannot see both Default Gateways when launching IPConfig, thus I am not able to log onto the LAN router. Is there any solution for what I am trying to achieve? I use a PC.

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:  
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :  
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ecb8:b66c:43bf:c3bd%5  
Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.78.144  
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0  
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :  
  
Wireless LAN adapter WiFi:  
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home  
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::eb1:50fa:a72c:7118%7  
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.2  
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0  
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: What _can_ you see in `ipconfig`, then?

Comment: @Matty this is not very readable, please add it to your question in the appropriate format

Comment: @u1686_grawity I added the output of IPConfig to the question. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Assuming it's not broken, maybe it's working in bridge/AP mode or have its DHCP disabled? Have you tried resetting (not rebooting) it first? Any physical switch for operation mode at the back? Any label showing its default IP? (Might be conflicting with that of the WiFi router?) Might want to check/share the model number as well so that you/we can try to check out the manual.

Comment: @Matty what's the LAN router's IP and subnet? You need to set your Ethernet's subnet to the same subnet your LAN router is in (just a different IP address). Currently, this is not the case, that's why you can access the LAN router.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to connect to the LAN router:

- Find out which subnet your LAN router uses (via its IP and subnet mask)
- Manually set your Ethernet adapter to the same subnet your LAN router is in.

Then you should be able to connect to your LAN router.

If you don't know your LAN router's subnet, reset it to its default configuration. If it has the same default as your WLAN router (192.168.0.1/24), you need to change it first by connecting your PC **only** to the LAN router (and manually set your Ethernet adapter to the same subnet your LAN router is in).